# How to convert HSM ECDSAPublicKey to java.security PublicKey

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, public-key, csr, hsm

I am trying to generate CSR(Certificate Signing Request) with the keys generated from HSM.

I am able to convert HSM RSA public key to java.security RSAPublicKey with modulus and public_exponent.

I am **NOT** able to convert HSM ECDSA public key to java.security EC PublicKey. I have Curve name(SECP256R1) and the EcPoint value for the public key I generated from HSM.

Can someone help on this?

Thanks!!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43965667/5128464)

Comment: thanks @vlp .. I tried this one for different curves. some of the curves have indifferent length. Meaning - I m not able to split the encoded public key into exact halves to get x and y components. Is there some way that I should look to separate x and y values for different curve types?

Comment: Encoding must be in line with ANSI X9.62 -- usually an uncompressed format is used (i.e. `0x04` followed by an even number of bytes. You just need to divide those bytes to halves and get the coordinates). Consider updating your question with example value of `CKA_EC_POINT` and `CKA_EC_PARAMS`...

Comment: Also see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/185520)